# Efficient way to validate a DB connection

Tags: java, database, sybase

The DB driver I am working with (for a sybase DB) does not implement a Connection.isValid(). What is the most efficient way I can validate a db connection using a query (or otherwise) in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Libraries such as C3P0 and DBCP allow you to provide a validation query which is typically something very simple such as "select 1".  Hence, you could take the same approach or simply use either of these libraries (my recommendation would be C3P0).

However, rather than testing the connection prior to executing your query you could simply attempt to execute and then retry the operation if it fails because the connection is invalid.  Alternatively you could consider a non-pooled connection approach where the connection is created on-the-fly each time (e.g. such as Spring's `DriverManagerDataSource`).

Comment: @Brad: The API documentation states: "Useful for test or standalone environments outside of a J2EE container".  It does not state not to use in a production environment and I see no reason why it's unsuitable.  Care to offer an explanation?

Comment: Hi Adamski, you're quite correct. It is technically possible to use DriverManagerDataSource I will remove my -1, however for those readers who do not have experience they should try to implement connection pooling in preference to DriverManagerDataSource in nearly all cases. I remember naively using DriverManagerDataSource in the past and the benefits of pooling are numerous. (I just tried to remove the -1 but I can't unless the answer is edited)

Comment: @Brad I've made a trivial edit to the answer.  However, I don't agree that readers without experience should use connection pooling by default.  The choice is completely dependent on the problem domain - For example, for a single threaded daemon process that accesses a database sporadically using a connection pool would be a complete waste of resources as there's no real requirement to maintain an open connection.  We used to use connection pooling for every application and one day realised we'd completely drained our database server of resources.

Comment: No problem, I have corrected the rating given this discussion. Re: your issue of draining server resources, that would indicate an incorrect configuration of your client connections rather than a problem that connection pools inherently create.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly agree with Adamski's comment about using "select 1 from table" as an efficient way of checking connectivity and using connection pooling (e.g. commons-dbcp, C3PO).

Application servers (e.g. Websphere) allow you to configure this validation for you so your applciation code doesn't have to know about it. You have the choice of always having the connection checked prior to using it, or the connection pool being validated when a new connections is created. You can also purge connections periodically in case they get stale.

If you're not running in an application server you can use Common DBCP with the properties described here:

http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html

Or C3PO and take a look at using the idleConnectionTestPeriod property. This link talks about use with Hibernate but its still relevant for C3PO generally

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool